# redirect user to new page PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I want to redirect the user to a new page, after the two IF statements are completed successfully.
I would like it to forward to booking.php

This is what I have now:

```
<?php 
//connect to database
$dbConnect = mysqli_connect('xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxx','xxxxx')
or die("<p>The database server is not available.</p>");
$dbSelect = mysqli_select_db( $dbConnect,'sxxxxxx_db' )
or die("<p>The database is not available.</p>");

if(empty($_GET['namefield']) || empty($_GET['pwdfield']) || empty($_GET['cpwdfield']) || empty($_GET['emailfield']) || empty($_GET['phonefield']) )
    {
    Echo "Not all details have been entered";
    }
    ELSE
    {
        $name = $_GET['namefield'];
        $email = $_GET['emailfield'];
        $phone = $_GET['phonefield'];

        //Inserts Name, Password ,email and phone in the MySQL table
  $sql = "INSERT INTO customer (Name,Email,Phone) VALUES (\"$name\",\"$email\",\"$phone\") ";
    mysqli_query($dbConnect,$sql);

        }

           //check password

        if ($_GET["pwdfield"] == ($_GET['cpwdfield']))
            {
        $password = $_GET['pwdfield'];
        $email = $_GET['emailfield'];

         $sql = "UPDATE customer SET Password='".$password."' WHERE Email='".$email."'";
                 mysqli_query($dbConnect,$sql);
        //Or die ("<p>Data unable to enter into database.</p>"."<p>Error code ". mysqli_errno($dbConnect). ": ".mysqli_error($dbConnect)). "</p>";  


        }
    ELSE
      {
      $sql = "DELETE from customer where Password ='".$password."'";
      mysqli_query($dbConnect,$sql);
  echo("<br>Password did not match! ");
  //  failed
      }
  mysqli_close($dbConnect); 

?>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks.

UPDATE:

I know I can use header but I need help to only direct after the if statements are correct.

Comment: Use `header` function of php.

Answer (score 1):

try to add where you want to redirect,

```
header('Location: booking.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use the header command, http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
header( 'Location: booking.php' );
```

for this. (Depending on the path of your booking.php file of course.)

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's http_redirect() which Redirects to the given url.

**Syntax :**

```
bool http_redirect ([ string $url [, array $params [, bool $session = false [, int $status = 0 ]]]] )
```

**Reference :**

Check [http_redirect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-redirect.php)

Answer (score 0):

IF header information is not passed thn try to redirect with script.

```
   echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
   window.location.href='sample.php';
   </SCRIPT>");
```